# Intellij's scala console not working

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I just updated my IntelliJ and scala plugin and now the scala console won't work (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> has no affect).

Intellij version: `14.1.1`
Scala plugin version `1.4.15`

Comment: What does CTRL + Enter do you normally?

Comment: On the scala console in IntelliJ, enter just goes to a new line, but ctrl+enter runs all code in the little window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment there seems to be a bug:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8391

Apart from that, you can try running the console from the terminal:

Go to the terminal (in bottom right) and execute scala.